# Missing closing parenthesis using DENSE_RANK() MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am not sure where my syntax is wrong here. I need to display the top vendors based on `invoice_total`

```
select *
from (
        select vendor_id, invoice_total,
        dense_rank () over(partition by vendor_id order by invoice_total asc)
          as ranking
        from invoices) a1
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `where a1.ranking = 1` for outer part of the SQL :

```
select *
from (
        select vendor_id, invoice_total,
        dense_rank () over(partition by vendor_id order by invoice_total asc)
          as ranking
        from invoices) a1
where a1.ranking = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL only supports `dense_rank()` in version 8+.  You can always use a correlated subquery:

```
select i.*
from invoices i
where i.invoice_total = (select max(i2.invoice_total)
                         from invoices i2
                         where i2.vendor_id = i.vendor_id
                        );
```

This assumes that "top vendors" refers to the *largest* totals, which is the opposite of your SQL.

There are other ways to express this.  I also like using tuples in MySQL:

```
select i.*
from invoices i
where (i.vendor_id, i.invoice_total) in
          (select i2.vendor_id, max(i2.invoice_total)
           from invoices i2
           group by i2.vendor_id
          );
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me `dense_rank` is for 8+. I was trying to impress my interviewer yesterday but kept getting a syntax error thankfully he knew exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: I seem to remember reading that performance for the tuples idea in MySQL is very poor - but I might have got that wrong